# Why it's hiding everything instead of concerned things when I click on a hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, show-hide

I'm displaying a list of questions alongwith their answers and correct answer. For this purpose I'm making use of HTML . Now there is one hyperlink present in each question titled **"Hide-Show Answers"**. When user clicks on this hyperlink **the 'Options' heading, options for that questions and a correct answer** should get hide if it's showing. If these things are hidden, then upon clicking on the  hyperlink these things should get shown. Initially when page loads everything should be displayed as like now. Also one more thing is when page loads initially everything would be shown to the user and the text of hyperlink should be **"Hide Anwsers"** and when user clicks on this link the content should get hidden and title should change to **"Show Answers"**. Following is my HTML of a questions table:

```
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="98%" style="padding:0 10px 0 10px;" align="center">
          <tbody>

            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="sub_name" id="" >
                  <div style="height:800px; overflow:scroll; width:100%;">
                      <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="manage_box"> 
                      <tr class="question_info">
                        <td valign="top">
                          <b>Question 1.<a href ="#" style="margin-left:300px;" class="fav_que" id="15957">Add To Favourite Question</a></b><br /><b>Direction : </b><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">


                          <br /><b>Question : </b>
                                                    <br/><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>The dimensions of universal gravitational constant are</p></body></html>
                                                                              <br/><b>QUE15957</b><br/>
                          <a href="#" class="show-ans">Hide-Show Answers</a> 
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                          <b>Options : </b>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                                                  <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     1 .

M-2L2T-2

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     2 .

M-1L3T-2

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     3 .

ML-1T-2

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     4 .

ML2T-2

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                          <b>Correct Answer :</b> 2   
                        </td>
                      </tr>              
                                      </table>
                            <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="manage_box"> 
                      <tr class="question_info">
                        <td valign="top">
                          <b>Question 2.<a href ="#" style="margin-left:300px;" class="fav_que" id="37672">Add To Favourite Question</a></b><br /><b>Direction : </b><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">


                          <br /><b>Question : </b>
                                                    <br/><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>If angular momentum quantum number can take value of <i>n</i> also (in addition to other possible values) then total number of electrons in first orbit would have been :</p></body></html>
                                                                              <br/><b>QUE37672</b><br/>
                          <a href="#" class="show-ans">Hide-Show Answers</a> 
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                          <b>Options : </b>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                                                  <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     1 .

2

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     2 .

6

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     3 .

8

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     4 .

10

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                          <b>Correct Answer :</b> 3   
                        </td>
                      </tr>              
                                      </table>
                            <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="manage_box"> 
                      <tr class="question_info">
                        <td valign="top">
                          <b>Question 3.<a href ="#" style="margin-left:300px;" class="fav_que" id="38552">Add To Favourite Question</a></b><br /><b>Direction : </b><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">


                          <br /><b>Question : </b>
                                                    <br/><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>For figure 24, the correct relation is -<br><img height="110" src="http://www.entranceprime.com/upload_media/questions/original/1328941281_38.JPG" width="172"></p></body></html>
                                                                              <br/><b>QUE38552</b><br/>
                          <a href="#" class="show-ans">Hide-Show Answers</a> 
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                          <b>Options : </b>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                                                  <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     1 .

<img src="http://localhost/eprime/entprm/web/ckeditor_3.6.1/plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/showimage.php?formula=9329a28849bd94b3bcc49e3a4b69a595.png" class="Wirisformula" align="middle">

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     2 .

<img src="http://localhost/eprime/entprm/web/ckeditor_3.6.1/plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/showimage.php?formula=c8c15583e8f5742625e6d80c71f3a691.png" class="Wirisformula" align="middle">

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     3 .

<img src="http://localhost/eprime/entprm/web/ckeditor_3.6.1/plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/showimage.php?formula=af6f96bda5c2f575fc42e4751c5772fe.png" class="Wirisformula" align="middle">

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     4 .

All of the above

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                          <b>Correct Answer :</b> 4   
                        </td>
                      </tr>              
                                      </table>

                        </div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
```

And the jQuery code I tried is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".show-ans").click(function(e){

  e.preventDefault();
      if($(this).parents("tbody").children("tr:last").is(":visible"))
      {
          $(this).parents("tbody").children("tr:not(:first)").hide();
      $(this).html("Show Answer");
      }
      else
      {
          $(this).parents("tbody").children("tr:not(:first)").show();
      $(this).html("Hide Answer");
      }
  });
});
```

Now my issue is when I click on a hyperlink of a specific question then only it's Options and correct options should hide. Other questions' content should be displayed as it is but this is not happening. when I click on a hyperlink of a specific question everything gets hide and including the hyperink I clicked. How should I correct this issue?

Comment: Your markup is not valid , check it on http://validator.w3.org/check

Comment: its working http://jsfiddle.net/JCVnY/27/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the code like this way

```
$(".show-ans").click(function(e){

  e.preventDefault();
  if($(this).parent().parent().parent().children("tr:last").is(":visible"))
  {
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().children("tr:not(:first)").hide();
  $(this).html("Show Answer");
  }
  else
  {
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().children("tr:not(:first)").show();
  $(this).html("Hide Answer");
  }
 });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JCVnY/29/)

Comment: It's working perfect. Upvoted your answer. Soon will accept it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: :Now my requirement has changed slightly. I want to keep the content hidden which I was showing on the form load according to previous requirement. Can you show me how to achieve this? I t would be of great help to me.

Comment: can you post it as another question with more explanation?

Comment: Actually your answer is working fine for me. I've also accepted it. But now my requirement is I want to keep the content hidden when initially form displays. Afterwards on clicking on the hyperlink I want to hide/show the content. The content is Options heading, actual options and the correct answer of that question. Also for all questions these thing should be hidden on form load initially. But when user clicks on the concerned question's hyperlink it should work for that question only which is now working. Can you please help me in this regard?

Comment: Anoop Joshi: I've posted a new question. The link or ot is as follows:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316799/how-to-show-hide-the-content-of-a-table-in-following-scenario-using-jquery

Comment: @PHPGeek I've given an answer to that question. Check that