# How to show/hide the content of a table in following scenario using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, show-hide

I'm using PHP, Smarty, jQuery, etc. for my website. I'm displaying a list of questions, it's available answer options and a correct answer for that question. Now there is a hyperlink with each question. When user clicks on the hyperlink of a specific question the content(**Options heading, actual options, correct answer**) for that specific question should hide if it's displaying and it should get display if the content is hidden. When content is shown the hyperlink should have text "Hide Answers" and when the content is hidden the text of hyperlink should be "Show Answers". One more thing is when the page loads initially the above content(**Options heading, actual options, correct answer**) for each question should be hidden and the text of hyperlink for each question should be "Show Answers". The HTML of this question list is as follows:

```
<div id="entrancelist">
        <h2 class="heading">favourite questions</h2>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="98%" style="padding:5px;" align="center">
          <tbody>

            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="sub_name" id="" >
                  <div style="height:auto; overflow:hidden; width:100%;">
                      <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="manage_box"> 
                      <tr class="question_info">
                        <td valign="top" width="70%">
                          <b>Question 1.</b></td>
                          <td valign="top" align="left" width="30%">
                          <b><a href ="#" style="margin-right:0px;" class="fav_que" id="16164">Remove From Favourite Question</a></b></td></tr>
                          <tr class="question_info">
                          <td valign="top" colspan="2">
                          <br /><b>Direction : </b><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">

                          </td></tr>
                          <tr class="question_info">
                          <td valign="top"> 
                          <b>Question : </b>
                                                    <br/><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>A 150 m long train is moving to north at a speed of 10 m/s. A parrot flying towards south with a speed of 5 m/s crosses the train. The time taken by the parrot the cross to train would be :<br></p></body></html>
                                                                            </td>
                        <td valign="bottom" align="right"><b>QUE16164</b></td>
                      </tr>
                        <tr class="question_info">                    
                          <td valign="top" colspan="2">
                          <a href="#" class="show-ans">Show Answers</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr> 
                      </td>                      
                    </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                          <b>Options : </b>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                                                  <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     1 .

30 s

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     2 .

15 s

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     3 .

8 s

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     4 .

10 s

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                          <b>Correct Answer :</b> 4   
                        </td>
                      </tr>              
                                      </table>
                            <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="manage_box"> 
                      <tr class="question_info">
                        <td valign="top" width="70%">
                          <b>Question 2.</b></td>
                          <td valign="top" align="left" width="30%">
                          <b><a href ="#" style="margin-right:0px;" class="fav_que" id="38552">Remove From Favourite Question</a></b></td></tr>
                          <tr class="question_info">
                          <td valign="top" colspan="2">
                          <br /><b>Direction : </b><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">

                          </td></tr>
                          <tr class="question_info">
                          <td valign="top"> 
                          <b>Question : </b>
                                                    <br/><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>For figure 24, the correct relation is -<br><img height="110" src="http://www.entranceprime.com/upload_media/questions/original/1328941281_38.JPG" width="172"></p></body></html>
                                                                            </td>
                        <td valign="bottom" align="right"><b>QUE38552</b></td>
                      </tr>
                        <tr class="question_info">                    
                          <td valign="top" colspan="2">
                          <a href="#" class="show-ans">Show Answers</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr> 
                      </td>                      
                    </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                          <b>Options : </b>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                                                  <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     1 .

<img src="http://localhost/eprime/entprm/web/ckeditor_3.6.1/plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/showimage.php?formula=9329a28849bd94b3bcc49e3a4b69a595.png" class="Wirisformula" align="middle">

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     2 .

<img src="http://localhost/eprime/entprm/web/ckeditor_3.6.1/plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/showimage.php?formula=c8c15583e8f5742625e6d80c71f3a691.png" class="Wirisformula" align="middle">

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     3 .

<img src="http://localhost/eprime/entprm/web/ckeditor_3.6.1/plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/showimage.php?formula=af6f96bda5c2f575fc42e4751c5772fe.png" class="Wirisformula" align="middle">

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     4 .

All of the above

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                          <b>Correct Answer :</b> 4   
                        </td>
                      </tr>              
                                      </table>
                            <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="manage_box"> 
                      <tr class="question_info">
                        <td valign="top" width="70%">
                          <b>Question 3.</b></td>
                          <td valign="top" align="left" width="30%">
                          <b><a href ="#" style="margin-right:0px;" class="fav_que" id="80763">Remove From Favourite Question</a></b></td></tr>
                          <tr class="question_info">
                          <td valign="top" colspan="2">
                          <br /><b>Direction : </b><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">

                          </td></tr>
                          <tr class="question_info">
                          <td valign="top"> 
                          <b>Question : </b>
                                                    <br/><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>Derive the expression for the time period of a simple pendulum which depends on the lenght, mass, and gravitational acceleration.</p></body></html>
                                                                            </td>
                        <td valign="bottom" align="right"><b>QUE80763</b></td>
                      </tr>
                        <tr class="question_info">                    
                          <td valign="top" colspan="2">
                          <a href="#" class="show-ans">Show Answers</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr> 
                      </td>                      
                    </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                          <b>Options : </b>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                                                  <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     1 .

<img src="http://localhost/eprime/entprm/web/ckeditor_3.6.1/plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/showimage.php?formula=b8bb97da575d595129425d5ba0cac48e.png" class="Wirisformula" align="middle">

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     2 .

<img src="http://localhost/eprime/entprm/web/ckeditor_3.6.1/plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/showimage.php?formula=2fa6f58b13fc7b4dbb999484c01320ca.png" class="Wirisformula" align="middle">

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     3 .

<img src="http://localhost/eprime/entprm/web/ckeditor_3.6.1/plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/showimage.php?formula=18d2b494bf784790e26d743900503669.png" class="Wirisformula" align="middle">

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td class="options" colspan="2">                     4 .

<img src="http://localhost/eprime/entprm/web/ckeditor_3.6.1/plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/showimage.php?formula=4e3da7281a68c57642beb71a7fddd9d6.png" class="Wirisformula" align="middle">

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                                            <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                          <b>Correct Answer :</b> 1   
                        </td>
                      </tr>              
                                      </table>
                        </div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
</div>
```

How should I achieve this? I tried a lot to achieve this but couldn't succeed. Caan anyone please help me in this regard? Thanks for spending some of your valuable time in understanding my issue. Waiting for your replies. The jQuery code I tried to show-hide the content is as follows. It's not working fine for me. Everything of the question gets hidden when I click on a hyperlink. But in this case the the content is showing when the form loads. Now I want the content hidden for each question when the form loads. On click of hyperlink it should work for concerned question. So please help me to achieve this:

```
$(".show-ans").click(function(e){

  e.preventDefault();
  if($(this).parent().parent().parent().children("tr:last").is(":visible"))
  {
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().children("tr:not(:first)").hide();
  $(this).html("Show Answer");
  }
  else
  {
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().children("tr:not(:first)").show();
  $(this).html("Hide Answer");
  }
 });
```

Comment: post your jQuery code what you have tried?

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle to understand in proper way.

Comment: use jquery accordion...http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: @Unknown,@kushal jain:I've added the code I tried to the question.

Comment: you could use $(this).closest('tr')... or $(this).closest('.classname')... instead of .parent().parent().parent().

Comment: You should use just <!DOCTYPE html> to support HTML5 instead of the HTML4 one - or better yet use no DOCTYPE throughout the body

Comment: @LukeWenke:Actually you are correct but that's not my issue for now. I can correct it later on. Can I get the solution for my issue now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in `document.ready()`

```
$(".show-ans").each(function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().parent().children("tr:not(:first)").hide();
  $(this).html("Show Answer");    
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JCVnY/31/)

**Edit**

```
$(".show-ans").each(function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().children("tr:not(:first)").hide();
        $(this).html("Show Answer");
        $(this).parent().parent().show();
    });

   $(".question_info").show();
    $(".show-ans").click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).parent().parent().parent().children("tr:last").is(":visible")) {
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().children("tr:not(:first)").hide();
            $(this).html("Show Answer");
        }
        else {
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().children("tr:not(:first)").show();
            $(this).html("Hide Answer");
        }
        $(this).parent().parent().show();
    });
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JCVnY/41/)

Comment: Anoop Joshi, by mistake you have taken HTML from my old question. The new HTML is totally different. Your idea works great with old HTML but not with the new HTML of table. Can you please make this idea workable on a new HTML which I've put into question?

Comment: Thanks for your help bro, but in this updated fiddle the question text is also getting hidden. It should be displayed. We don't have to do anything with it. The things we need to show/hide starts from the Options heading. Can you please correct this issue and update your fiddle?

Comment: :Initially when page loads it's hiding the options and correct answer as per my expectation. But when I click on Show Answer then also it works fine. But the issue is there when I click on Hide Answers. It's hiding everything including the question text. Actually it should not hide the question text when I click on Hide Answers. Can you please make this small change and update your fiddle accordingly? Thanks bro once again for your help.

Comment: @PHPGeek i've updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JCVnY/41/ Please accept the answer if it helped you

Comment: It's working perfect. I've accepted your answer and upvoted too. Thank you so much brother for your immense help.